# what could make session that was set in login page but lost when redirect?

Tags: php

I have a problem with my script. I have been using this same script for  months. Lat week I got a message from my client that cannot access their 
dashboard anymore. I check it was showing too much redirect problem. I 
quickly made attempt to solve this programming but all availed. I found out 
that the session actually set on the Login page because I echo it out 
without redirecting, but whenever I redirect to member dashboard the session 
variable will be undefined. I have gone through other people similar problem
on this forum but none were able to proffer solution to my problem. Because 
this same script has been working for months. Please take a look at the code 
and help me out.

This is Login page. Login.php The session actually set because when display LoginId when I echo echo it out. but lost when redirecting to another page. though It was working for more four months before this unexpected problem

```
<?php 
require("includes/config.php"); 
require_once(ROOT_PATH . "main/class.member.php");

$auth_member = new MEMBER();
if($auth_member->is_loggedin() != ""){
        $auth_member->redirect(BASE_URL.'member');
    }
if(isset($_POST['loginMemBtn'])){
        $userLoginID = strip_tags($_POST['userID']);
        $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

        if($auth_member->memberLogin($userLoginID, $password)){
            $auth_member->redirect(BASE_URL.'member');
        }
        else{
            $error[] = "Inccorrect Login Details!";
        }   
    }
?>
```

class.member.php 
This is the class that holds all the member details and where the session 
was set. It contain MemberLogin Function

```
<?php
session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    require_once(ROOT_PATH.'includes/dbconnect.php');

    // Class
    class MEMBER{   
        private $connect;
        public function __construct(){
            $database = new Database();
            $db = $database->dbConnection();
            $this->connect = $db;
        }

        public function lastInsertId(){
            return $this->connect->lastInsertId();
        }

        public function runQuery($sql){
            $stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql);
            return $stmt;
        }


        public function memberLogin($userLoginID, $password){
            try {
                $stmt = $this->connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM members 
                    WHERE status='Active'
                    AND (email=:email OR phone=:phone  OR username=:email) 
");
    $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$userLoginID, ':phone'=>$userLoginID));
                $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)               {
                    if(password_verify($password, $userRow['password'])) {
                        $_SESSION['member_session'] = $userRow['login_id'];
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function is_allowuser(){
            if(isset($_SESSION['member_session'])) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public function redirect($url){
            header("Location: $url");
        }

        public function doMememberLogout(){
            session_destroy();
            unset($_SESSION['member_session']);
            return true;
        }
    }

?>
```

session.php this file that check whether session is set or not and it 
include i to all other script

```
<?php
    $session = new MEMBER();
    if(!$session->is_allowuser()){
        $session->redirect(BASE_URL.'login');
        exit();
    }else{
        $auth_member = new MEMBER();    
        $loginID = $_SESSION['member_session'];
        $stmt = $auth_member->runQuery("SELECT * FROM members WHERE 
login_id=:loginID");
        $stmt->execute(array(":loginID"=>$loginID));
        $userInfo = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($userInfo['status'] != 'Active'){
            unset($_SESSION['member_session']);
        }   
    }
    ?>
```

This is  dashboard.php this is the page  that member redirect to from Login 
Page

```
<?php
 require("../includes/config.php"); 
    require_once(ROOT_PATH . "main/class.member.php");
    require_once(ROOT_PATH . "main/session.php");
     //echo $_SESSION['member_session'];
     ?>
```

Comment: dashboard.php,session.php both files need to start session  - session_start();

Comment: If I added session_start(); it will showing error that session has already started in class.member.php

Comment: have you by chance upgraded to PHP 7?

Comment: No. The script has been used for months. its only this session that is not working.

Comment: in class.member.php set error_teporting(0); for a movement  and check session not sure but i face same problem its solve by setting session_start() on each page.

Comment: but it not reporting any error . No error in  error log

Answer (score 0):

```
public function redirect($url){
   header("Location: $url");
   exit;
}
```

Use **exit** after header call in redirect method of class.member.php file

Comment: It is not working. I have already done that inside index.php  when accessing my controller .**<?php header("Location: dashboard");
 exit();?>**  I have been using this same script for more than four months just started this session error some days ago.

Comment: The problem still persists. what could make the same scripts which has been working for months suddenly stopped working because the session now lost when redirect?

Comment: someone should kindly help me. none of the above suggestions work. more idea will be appreciated.